# If I have an x11 "Window", how can I tell if it is the root window?

Tags: c, x11, xlib

If I have an x11 "Window", how can I tell if it is the root window?

I've found a few examples of enumerating windows, but that sounds like more than should be necessary.  Can 'win' be checked directly?

```c
int is_root_win(Window win)
{
  return /* What do I put here? */;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with calling XQueryTree?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Nothing, but was wondering if there was a XGetRootWindow() call or something.

Comment: There is such function but you need to know the screen to use it (RootWindow or RootWindowOfScreen). There is DefaultRootWindow but your window may or may not be on the default screen. In most cases there is only one screen, but this is by no means guaranteed.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. That might work.  I'm playing with the `compiz` code so I might have access to a screen object. Thanks for the hint!